# Even with srand (time(NULL)) out of the loop, numbers are the same for a period of time

Tags: c, random, numbers, srand

I have a simple code in C and there is a random number generation code in the middle.. problem is that for a long period of time that number stays the same and then goes one up! rand_pick might be 5 for over 30 times you run the C program and then will change finally to 6,...
I wanted to know why and if there is another way to produce a really random 1 to 9 digit.

```
int rand_pick;
srand (time(NULL));
rand_pick = 1 + (int) (9.0*rand()/(RAND_MAX+1.0));
```

Thanks a lot ;)

Comment: I still `srand` .. please post the *actual* code.

Comment: 'Even with srand (time(NULL)) out of the loop, numbers are the same for a period of time' -- No they aren't.

Answer (score 2):

No, numbers should be quasi random. You can run this snippet of code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define RANDOM_COUNT 10000

int main(void) {
    int rand_count[10] = {};
    int rand_pick;
    int i;

    srand (time(NULL));

    // run number of experiments
    for(i = 0; i < RANDOM_COUNT; i++) {
        rand_pick = 1 + (int) (9.0*rand()/(RAND_MAX+1.0));
        rand_count[rand_pick]++;
    }

    for(i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
        printf("%d => %.3f %%\n", i, rand_count[rand_pick] /((float) RANDOM_COUNT));
    }   
}
```

It will randomly pick 10,000 numbers and count their distribution.  I always get uniform distribution:

```
1 => 0.111 %
2 => 0.111 %
3 => 0.111 %
4 => 0.111 %
5 => 0.111 %
6 => 0.111 %
7 => 0.111 %
8 => 0.111 %
9 => 0.111 %
```

Comment: Thanks for your replies.. but this random generation method I have is generating same number for minutes, until it goes one up (from 3 to 4 and finally 9 back to 1)! then the rest of the code uses the 2 lines below to get a 1 to 9 number from user and later compare them, but if you get to know the random generated number you can win this number guessing game for a while.                                 char pick = getchar();
int user_pick = atoi(&pick);

Comment: litegait: Have you tried my snippet? If you get an uniform distribution, the problem is would be in the initialization of the generator. Otherwise, there might be a problem within the generator.

Answer (score 1):

You only want to initialize srand once in your program. If you are running the program several times a second for some reason then you need to get a random number from somewhere else (like /dev/random on linux) to seed your random number generator.

Comment: Or else use srand() to initialise one RNG, and then use that first RNG to initialise as many more RNGs as you need.

Comment: @rossum I'm not sure what you mean by "more RNGs". The C library only supports one RNG, so those would have to be custom built.

Comment: Doesn't C have threading?  A simple LCG RNG is very easy to code, just copy the C source into your thread.

Comment: Hmm, I guess if I were to look for a multithreaded solution where I had to code anyway I'd do something where they shared an RNG. Make the RNG thread aware, probably not by locking, probably use some sort of atomic operations. However, I'm pretty sure threading is digressed from what the question is about :P

Comment: Thanks for the replies.. but this random generation method I have is generating same number for minutes, until it goes one up (from 3 to 4 and finally 9 back to 1)! then the rest of the code uses the 2 lines below to get a 1 to 9 number from user and later compare them, but if you get to know the random generated number you can win this number guessing game for a while.                                 char pick = getchar();
int user_pick = atoi(&pick);

Comment: @litegait Does time(NULL) return the same value for you for minutes? (If so, your C implementation is broken)